# Windows Command FOR LOOP - how to use previous value of counter?

Tags: windows, loops, parameters, command

using Windows Command, I would like to use the previous counter value to specify a file within a command.
Something like:

```
FOR /L %G in (1,1,3) do (echo %G & echo (%G-1)
```

Expected result:

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
```

Is this possible somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, for your purpose, you can run the command:

```
$for /L %i in (1,1,3) do @echo off | set /P=%i & set /a myvar=-1+%i & echo.
```

The output is:
[image: echo counter and previous counter]

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
```